# Dynamics CRM How to inactivate a record after deletion of connections

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, delete-record

I have 3 entites like List, Member, ListMember. And of course I use the connection entity.

I wrote a workflow which works when a List and a Member are connected to each other. This workflow adds a new record to the ListMember entity with fields List and Member. There is no problem with that workflow so far.

I need another workflow to delete that record when the connection between its List and Member is cut. I think there is no deletion option in a workflow, unless I use a plug-in. So, I thought that I can just inactivate that record and show the user only the active records. I don't have to use the classic Status (active-inactive) option, I can use a different Yes-No button as well; that is I just have to reach the record in the ListMember entity which keeps the List and the Member that used to be connected to each other.

However, I cannot do it as when I use Connection as main entity of the workflow and pick "when the record is deleted" to trigger the workflow, the only records that I can inactivate are "Connection", "Connected to (entity name)", "Connected from (entity name)", "Currency" and "Role". When I select "Connected to (ListMember)" or "Connected from (ListMember)", it looks for the a connection between List and the ListMember records and naturally does not find any. And I can't reach ListMember directly.

How can I reach and inactivate that record in the ListMember entity?

Comment: if you feel up to it, you can actually add your answer as an answer and then mark that one the resolution...thus closing the question ;-)

Comment: Aa, I didn't think that that would be a normal act =) Ok I'll do it =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it:

I added a ListMember lookup in the Connection entity. Add another step in the first workflow which adds the ListMember to the Connection record. Then in the status changer workflow, I selected that ListMember record to update.